# Ford-Falkerson's algorithm for undirected graphs (What am I missing?)

Tags: linear-programming

I "found" an algorithm for finding maximum flow in undirected graph which I think isn't correct, but I can't find my mistake. Here is my algorithm:
   We construct a new directed graph in the following way: for every edge ${u,v}$ we create edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$ with $c((u,v))=c((v,u))=c({u,v})$. Then we apply Ford-Falkerson's algorithm on new graph. Now we make a flow in our first graph in the following way: Let's $f((u,v))\ge f((v,u))$, than we direct edge ${u,v}$ from $u$ to $v$ and take $f'((u,v))=f((u,v))-f((v,u))$. Now it will be maximum flow for our undirected graph, because otherwise we will construct a flow for corresponding directed graph, which is contradiction. 
   The reason that I think I have missed something is that there is an article on the Internet about this problem and I don't think anybody would wrote an article about such a trivial problem.

And this is the article: http://www.inf.ufpr.br/pos/techreport/RT_DINF003_2004.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ford-Fulkerson is not the best algorithm to find maximum flow in a directed graph, and in the undirected case it is possible to do much better (close to linear-time if I recall correctly).

You don't cite the article you are talking about, but it is most likely that it describe an algorithm which is much better than yours.

For many problems in optimization, it is not difficult to find an algorithm that gives an optimal solution; nevertheless there is a lot of work to find the most efficient ones.